# Add multiple suffixes to a string

Tags: bash, unix, range

I want to append suffixes in a range to a string `foo` located in `file`. The file is guaranteed to have just one line with the string.

I have been able to do this in Bash with:

```
for num in {001..003}; do
  echo $(cat file) $num
done
```

Which outputs the desired:

```
foo 001
foo 002
foo 003
```

But I was wondering if there's a better way to do it without the for loop.

I've tried things like:

```
$ echo $(cat file) {001..003}
foo 001 002 003
$ echo {001..003} | cat file -
foo
001 002 003
```

Comment: is `file` guaranteed to have just the one line? could `file` have multiple lines and if so could you update the question with a sample input and the desired output?

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed to have just one line. I'll update the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `printf` in `bash`:

```sh
s=$(<file)
printf "$s %s\n" {001..003}

foo 001
foo 002
foo 003
```

Assuming content of `file` doesn't contain any `printf` formatting directive.